# Can a photon excite an electron via the uncertainty principle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, electrons, potential

An electron is trapped in an infinite well potential with a width of $\Delta x$. A photon of wavelength $\lambda $ < $\Delta x$ is fired at the electron and misses or rather they don't interact. However it did pass within $\Delta x$ of the electron.

If this limits the location of the electron further, would this cause the uncertainty in the electrons momentum to increase therefore giving it the possibility of exciting it to a higher energy state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However it did pass within Δx of the electron.

The Δx is not the difference in space with the electron, as the electron is bound to a nucleus with a potential simulated by "an infinite potential well" . The Δx is related to the whole system, from the center of its mass as  a possible location to start with.

So the problem is : "photon + atom" as a whole. The photon does not "see" the electron.

To get the photon absorbed its wavelength should be within the width of the energy level differences between  the possible transition lines for the  electron .

Comment: I am not not talking about an atom I am trying to imagine a simplified version of a one dimensional infinite square potential. Also I am not even allowing for absorption as a possibility. I am imagining a rare scenario where the photon passes near but does not interact with the electron. The point of the question is to see if the photon essentially probes the space letting us know that the electron is in an even more confined width. And, would this result in a change in the energy state of the electron.

Comment: still, the photon does not "see" the electron, it sees the whole construct you made, "potential + electron" , it cannot "probe" with its arrival it is a different potential problem. It cannot be fired at the electron , as the electron's position is given by a probability anyway. A high energy photon can disrupt an atom as a whole, and thus its electon, but you are positing an infinite potential well so I do not see how it could be penetrated, except with the new probabilistic solution of the setup "photon +potential well +electron".

Comment: The electron is in a one dimensional segment of space and is trapped there. If the space were to be cut in half then the electron would be further confined giving rise to a greater uncertainty in momentum. If what I just said is accurate then my question is: can a photon which passes near the electron without hitting it essentially tell you where the electron is not located therefore the electron behaves as if it's in a smaller segment. It's ok if this is wrong. I would like to know why though. (Also, thanks for being patient and responding)

Comment: Once again, you are not positing a free electron so that the photon can interact with it. The photon sees the whole construct, cannot "see" the electron in the infinite potential well. It is an unphysical situation your are envisaging. A free electron occupies space with a HUP probability distribution. An electron bound in an infinite  potential is in a probability distribution within the space of the potential ,  mathematically given by the solution of the problem, much more constrained than the HUP, but in a sub world of its own. It cannot see the photon. "electron+potential" see it.

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand what you are saying. So, the electron doesn't behave differently because as far as it is concerned the photon isn't there? But what about the double slit experiment which proves the electron "knows" about possibilities even if that possibility doesn't occur. Can you describe a situation in which a photon not interacting with something limits where something can possibly be located? At the quantum scale.

Comment: One always needs an interaction. In the case of the double slit the interaction is "electron (or photon) + screen atom". All of the quantum mechanical probabilistic formulations are about quantum mechanical entities ( particles , atoms, molecules etc) "knowing" within their functional dependence. That knowledge gets manifest by an individual interaction, and a sequence of interactions gives the QM probability distribution for the specific problem.

Comment: Ok. Then I'll create a specific problem. Imagine the double slit experiment where we try to observe which slit the electron goes through. So we shine photons to have a look by sending them through both slits as well. Now, if the photons have a wavelength smaller than a slit and as chance would have it none of them ever hit an electron, the interference pattern over time will still appear. I'm wondering if the photons not hitting the electrons effectively means the slits were narrower and therefore result in a different interference pattern.

Comment: Have a look at this experiment http://phys.org/news/2011-01-which-way-detector-mystery-double-slit.html . Bye bye, I have chores to do.

Comment: Similar in a way: [Magnetic solenoid effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov%E2%80%93Bohm_effect#Magnetic_solenoid_effect), probably you'll find an example you are looking for.